# FIWARE IoT Stack open source code

Tags: iot, fiware, fiware-orion

Is there a place where I can find the source code of Fiware IoT Stack? ( https://catalogue.fiware.org/iot_stack)

Comment: Your question is offtopic, and I'm voting to close it.

Answer (score 0):

Fiware IoT Stack is available at github, [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-iot-stack).

Answer (score 0):

The FIWARE IoT Stack is composed of several pieces, e.g. IOTAGents, Context Broker, etc. You can find source code at the FIWARE organization at Github: https://github.com/fiware

Note that some repositories there are actually "mirrors" or the right ones in other place. For intance, https://github.com/Fiware/context.Orion is a mirror of the actual Orion Context Broker source code repository at https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion